# CSS background cover not taking full display screen after converting to wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Please see the image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXpDj.png)

In bootstrap static design the cover image is okay. But after converting to WordPress using underscore theme i get the problem. I checked using inspect element. But none of WordPress/underscore style overlapping this.

I don't know what to do. I would really appreciate if any helps me there.

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please add your code in the post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

we can't help without the code, but for sure, your background is on a div, on or the body tag, that's just too small, so putting it's height to 100%, or setting the background on the html tag (no tested, but i think it's always at least 100% height) should do the work.

Comment: Exactly!! There was a div: <div id="page" class="site"> inside header.

Answer (score 0):

Neil is correct in his response. We can't help without the code.

In genral, there are several ways to achieve CSS background covering full display screen:

You can try this code for css:

```
background: url("your image URL") no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
```

Or you can learn more stuff on this link: [W3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)